# Man pages for clang unavailable

Tags: 16.04, manpage, clang

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I've installed clang via apt.
When I try to look at the man page, I'm told that the man page is unavailable. Man pages for other things (eg. man gcc) work fine.

What might be going wrong? How can I resolve this? Any pointers on where to look would be appreciated.

```
ian@ian-VirtualBox:~$ man clang
No manual entry for clang
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
ian@ian-VirtualBox:~$ man 7 undocumented
No manual entry for undocumented in section 7

ian@ian-VirtualBox:~$ clang --version
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Running man clan-3.8 results in:

```
ian@ian-VirtualBox:~$ man clang-3.8
No manual entry for clang-3.8
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

The directory /usr/share/man/man1 contains:

```
ian@ian-VirtualBox:/usr/share/man/man1$ ls | grep clang
clang-apply-replacements-3.8.1.gz
clang-check-3.8.1.gz
```

The output of ls /usr/bin/*clang* is:

```
ian@ian-VirtualBox:/usr/share/man/man1$ ls /usr/bin/*clang*
/usr/bin/clang                         /usr/bin/clang-check-3.8
/usr/bin/clang++                       /usr/bin/clang-cl-3.8
/usr/bin/clang-3.8                     /usr/bin/clang-query
/usr/bin/clang++-3.8                   /usr/bin/clang-query-3.8
/usr/bin/clang-apply-replacements      /usr/bin/clang-rename-3.8
/usr/bin/clang-apply-replacements-3.8  /usr/bin/clang-tblgen
/usr/bin/clang-check
```

dpkg -L clang-3.8 shows man pages for clang-apply-replacements, clang-check, scan-build and scan-view. I'm able to bring up these man pages OK

Installing clang-3.8-doc installs a lot of things in usr/share/doc but no man pages. Is this what I should be using for clang documentation instead of man?

Comment: does the directory `/usr/share/man/man1/` contain a file starting with clang? and btw does `man clang-3.8` work?

Comment: What is the output of : `ls /usr/bin/*clang*`.

Comment: Maybe you need to install `clang-3.8-doc` as well. Look into `dpkg -L clang-3.8` if there are manpages installed with the base package.

Comment: The files list in http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/clang-3.8/filelist says there are manpages for `clang-apply-replacements`, `clang-check`, `scan-build` and `scan-view`.

Answer (score 3):

The [package `clang`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clang&searchon=all&suite=yakkety&section=all) does not install a manual page. You may want to install `clang-3.8-doc` which installs documentation in HTML format in `/usr/share/doc/clang-3.8-doc/html/`; point your browser to `/usr/share/doc/clang-3.8-doc/html/index.html`.